# Move Records to bottom of a spreadsheet if it contains a 0

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to move an entire row to the bottom of a spread sheet if the column k contains a 0. The code I have only works on change not on activate or even better yet with a button. How would i modify the code to work outside of on change?

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
 Dim rw As Long
 Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:K")) Is Nothing And LCase(Target) = 0 Then
rw = Target.Row
    Target.EntireRow.Cut Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
Rows(rw).Delete
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is column K a numerical column? Could you just sort your rows largest to smallest?

Comment: It is, but if I need it sorted smallest to largest with the zeroes at the end. If there is a way outside of VBA I would like that answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

 Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long

 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = Lastrow - 1 To 1 Step -1

        If .Range("K" & i).Value = 0 Then

            Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

            .Rows(i).Cut .Rows(Lastrow + 1)

            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    Next i

 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: No change, It does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Make sure you modify the code to fit you needs. Change sheet name in the with statement if needed. Code is fully tested and it s work.

Comment: Yeah i did that and I noticed a space between Rows(i).Cut   .Rows(Lastrow+1)

Comment: I fixed the space and not I get object required on that line.

Comment: you get an error because is not a space. It s copy/cut paste method.

Comment: Thank you I saw my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have an answer, but since your wanted to `Sort` also, this code works.

```
Sub SortMoveRowstolRow()
Dim fRow As Long, lRow As Long

    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Sort Key1:=Range("K1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

        fRow = .Range("K:K").Find(what:=0, after:=.Range("K1"), Lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End With

    Rows(1 & ":" & fRow).EntireRow.Cut Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Rows(1 & ":" & fRow).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```